# Why won't my HTML link up with my CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm following a tutorial online but I can't seem to link up my CSS with the HTML code. I have both files placed in the same folder. The files are called tut.html and tut.css

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 Tutorial</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='tut.css'/>
</head>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">navigation1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">navigation2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
<p>here is the sidebar</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
<p>here is the content</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<p>Here is the footer</p>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #wrapper {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 96%;
}
#header {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 940px;
}
#navigation {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 940px;
}
#navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 58px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 698px;
}
#sidebar {
  border-right-color: #e8e8e8;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  margin-top: 58px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
}
#footer {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  clear: both;
  width: 940px;
}
```

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: Is tut.css in the same folder as your html file?

Comment: @Doorknob well it doesn't link up with my html? meaning it doesn't style the html file or anything.

Comment: I see a problem, you are missing <body> tags in your HTML.  Probably whats causing your issue.

Comment: @Michael nope that doesn't fix it

Comment: Ahh! You have no body! Jokes. Just add the `<body>` and `</body>` tag and see if that helps. :) Also check the location of the css file. Is it in the same directory as this file?

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Try adding a doctype as @ralph.m suggested.  Just google XHTML transitional doctype.

Comment: @Michael, in HTML5, the `<head>` and `<body>` tags are implicitly added, and can be safely left off, however the doctype declaration cannot.

Comment: Guess he is missing <!Doctype html> at top then? handy links: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-doctype http://www.w3schools.com/tags/

Comment: If you exactly have two files **tut.html** and **tut.css** in a same folder, it must work. I think there is a typo in your file names. Your HTML/CSS works fine.

Comment: @zzzzBov this is certainly true, except for in the case of IE.  Which can still be retarded about rendering in that situation

Comment: @goodfriend DOCTYPE declaration is not important for CSS at this step.

Comment: What are you using as an editor?  When you made the css file is there a chance that it is actually saved improperly and saved as tut.css.html?

Comment: @NOX yeah but still he should learn to write the documents properly ;D
@user182 what browser are you using? can u send us screenshot of your output just to be sure? btw I would really add the type, just to be sure... `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='tut.css'/>`

Comment: @goodfriend Yes, you are right. Also `type` attribute is not necessary.

Comment: You need to use this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\the_path_to_the_folder\file.css` As if you are just testing it. Else, if you are using some other software like WebMatrix you might try using. `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='~/tut.css'/>`

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid.  You are missing `<body>` tags in your HTML which is probably the source of your issue.  If you did not, you should also provide a doctype at the top of the page.  Make your html this:

```
<!doctype html>    
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 Tutorial</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='tut.css'/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">navigation1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">navigation2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
<p>here is the sidebar</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
<p>here is the content</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<p>Here is the footer</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Incorrect. `<body>` and `</body>` are optional! See the [HTML5 documentation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags).

Comment: @MrLister ever heard of IE?

Comment: I dare you to show me a HTML file that IE treats differently with and without those tags. PS I don't have IE6.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **exactly** this file:

```
tut.css
```

And it is in the same folder as `tut.html`, then, your HTML/CSS must works correctly, as it worked for me fine in all browsers.
Maybe you have save the CSS file by such this name: `tut.css.txt`.

If you are using Windows, follow this instructions to be sure of your file name:

1. Open My Computer
2. From `View` menu, select `Folder and Search Options`
3. In the `View` tab of opened window, diselect this option: **Hide extensions for known file types**
4. Apply and Ok

[image]

Now you must see the complete name of your css file.